# Change all translations inputs together

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I'm using this pluginn http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-translate. What is the best way to use this to translate all fields (from the backend) together instead of one by one?

Comment: What do you mean by translating them all together?
You'll still have to add the translated string to each untranslated string.

Comment: I mean when a user write a page with title, subtitle, description he have to select a language from each this field , it would be much better  if there is one global option list to select instead.If use the translate plugin and static pages plugin you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CTRL+click on the language selection dropdown at any field will change the language for all the input fields at once.